# ¿Cómo cargar una pagina web o archivo HTML como fondo de pantalla de escritorio?

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web, electron, aplicación-escritorio

Tengo una pequeña aplicación hecha con javaScript, html, css sobre Electron, sin embargo me gustaría poder cargar esta pagina web en mi escritorio. En principio estoy usando Windows 10, pero busco que sea multiplataforma, la idea es que funcione en cualquier SO.

La preguntas es, ¿hay alguna manera con programación, ya sea usando python, java, javascript de cargar mi pagina web como fondo de pantalla de escritorio, o hay alguna información que me pueda ayudar a cumplir mi objetivo?.

Comment: Suponiendo que te refieras a ocupar **todo** el escritorio con tu aplicación o página web, puedes ejecutar el navegador en modo "kiosk". Busca info sobre eso en la red a ver si te sirve.

Comment: @masterguru disculpa, no me hice entender bien y es por eso que he corregido mi pregunta, me refiero a cargar mi pagina web como fondo de pantalla de escritorio, haciendo uso de Node.js u otro lenguaje. Si tienes alguna información que pueda serme de ayuda, te lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de que te refieras copiar una página web completa (incluyendo peticiones HTTP) opino que la mejor opción es usar `nativefier`. Nativefier es una herramienta que se puede instalar con `npm` muy facil de usar. En primer lugar la necesitas instalar, para ello debes tener instalado Node.js. Una vez instalado Node.js instalas Nativefier con el comando: `npm install --global nativefier` una vez este instalado solo tendrás que ejecutar el comando: `nativefier <url web>` desde el directorio donde quieres que se guarde la aplicación de escritorio. Estas aplicaciones son creadas mediante Electron, sin embargo si desea más información te dejo la [documentación oficial](https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier). Espero haberte ayudado con tu duda.

Comment: Me fue de mucha ayuda @Asier, sin embargo no me hice entender bien y es por eso que corregí mi pregunta, mi intención es cargar mi pagina web como fondo de escritorio, ya sea con Node.js o con otro lenguaje de programación que pueda complementar mi App hecha en Electron. Si me pudieses ayudar te lo agradecería muchísimo.